# windows 8.1 tile background and image is not set correctly

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-8.1, tiles, pinned-site

Have set up my website on github pages: [w8tiles](http://yaroslavya.github.io/w8tile/)
I use [buildmypinnedsite](http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com/en) to create all the markup and images.
I open the site in ie11 on windows 8.1. Add the site to the applications and see an ie logo with some random background color(that is usually the same for all sites I add). I pin the site to start and its still an ie logo with some background color that doesnt match the one I define in browserconfig.xml.
Below is the code to set the background and tile in html. Same code is in the browserconfig.

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#603cba">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-144x144.png">
```

The question is: what am I doing wrong and why the images I add as a tiles are ignored? Note: I added all the images to the root and checked that they are all available via the link + browserconfig.xml is available too.

The detailed desciption of the issue is listed [here](https://github.com/RealFaviconGenerator/realfavicongenerator/issues/129)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/04/03/pinned-sites-in-windows-8.aspx - are you using IE in metro mode?

Comment: Looks like you solved it? From your comments on the Github issue list?

Comment: Yes, its solved, just need some time to put together an answer and post it here. Hope it helps to someone who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 key points:

1. You need IE to be your browser by default. Or the live tiles are not updated. Even if it was your browser by default and the tiles were live, once you make chrome, opera or any other browser your browser by default live updates will stop.
2. IE should be in a metro mode. If its in a usual mode, the favicon will be retrieved and browserconfig.xml or any metategs are ignored. Also tile background in this case is set by favicons color(not sure how it is calculated, but depending on the color of your favicon the color of the tile will be set).

You can find more details in the [github issue](https://github.com/RealFaviconGenerator/realfavicongenerator/issues/129).